# Issues with Nintegrate - different methods yielding different values (both giving warnings)

Tags: numerical-integration, numerics, integral-equations, precision-and-accuracy

I am integrating the following function

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2d^{2}}\times\frac{\sqrt{\omega_{c}\left|t_1-t_2\right|}-\sqrt{\pi}e^{\frac{1}{\omega_{c}\left|t_1-t_2\right|}}\text{erfc}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{\omega_{c}\left|t_1-t_2\right|}}\right)}{\left(\omega_{c}\left|t_1-t_2\right|\right){}^{3/2}}
\end{equation}

```
\[Delta]Et\[Delta]E0[t1_,t2_,\[Omega]c_,d_]:=(1/(2*d^2))*((Sqrt[Abs[t1-t2]*\[Omega]c]-E^(1/(Abs[t1-t2]*\[Omega]c))*Sqrt[Pi]*Erfc[1/Sqrt[Abs[t1-t2]*\[Omega]c]])/(Abs[t1-t2]*\[Omega]c)^(3/2))
```

with $\omega_c=1$ and $d=1$, yielding the following limits

```
Limit[\[Delta]Et\[Delta]E0[t1, t2, 1, 1] /. t1 - t2 -> t, t -> 0]
(*1/4*)
Limit[\[Delta]Et\[Delta]E0[t1, t2, 1, 1] /. t1 - t2 -> t, t ->Infinity]
(*0*)
```

The integral is given by

```
Nint[(t_)?NumericQ,(\[CapitalOmega]_)?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[\[Delta]Et\[Delta]E0[t1, t2, \[Omega]ca, da]*E^(I*\[CapitalOmega]*(t1-t2)),{t1,zero,t},{t2,zero,t}, AccuracyGoal -> 8,PrecisionGoal -> 8, MaxRecursion -> 50, WorkingPrecision -> 100]
```

However, for the "DoubleExponential" method, I am getting the message:

[image]

On the other hand, if I choose to not declare any particular method, I obtain

[image]

**Note:** it is also interesting to note that different Methods are yielding different values for this integral. So I do not know which result I should trust.

As suggested by @Akku14's answer, I could use the following alternative integral instead

```
Ninta[t_, \[CapitalOmega]_] := 2*NIntegrate[\[Delta]Et\[Delta]E0[t1, t2, 1, 1]*Cos[\[CapitalOmega]*(t1 - t2)], {t1, 0, t}, {t2, 0, t1}, Exclusions -> t1 == t2]
Ninta[10, 1]
```

However, this is also giving me some warnings/errors

[image]

Comment: In view of the output of `Normal[Series[(1/(2*d^2))*((Sqrt[RealAbs[t1 - t2]*\[Omega]c] - 
        E^(1/(Abs[t1 - t2]*\[Omega]c))*Sqrt[Pi]*
         Erfc[1/Sqrt[RealAbs[t1 - t2]*\[Omega]c]])/(RealAbs[
          t1 - t2]*\[Omega]c)^(3/2)) /. t1 - t2 -> x, {x, 0, 1}]]` i.e. $\frac{\sqrt{\pi } \left(\frac{1}{\text{$\omega $c}}\right)^{3/2} e^{\frac{1}{x \text{$\omega $c}}}}{2 d^2 x^{3/2}}-\frac{\sqrt{\pi } e^{\frac{1}{x \text{$\omega $c}}}}{2 d^2 x^{3/2} \text{$\omega $c}^{3/2}}$ if $x>0$, there are strong doubts about the convergence of this improper integral at the origin.

Comment: @user64494 I took the limit of this function, and I have $\rightarrow 1$ for $x\rightarrow 0$ and $\rightarrow 0$ for $x\rightarrow \infty$. So what do you mean by improper integral at the origin?

Comment: People here generally like users to post complete, working *Mathematica* code (an [MWE](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2126/what-do-we-mean-by-a-self-contained-minimal-working-example)). It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.

Comment: @sined: Can you support your claim " I have →1 for x→0" by code? TIA.

Comment: @user64494 I meant I am taking the limit using Mathematica, and this actually agrees with the asymptotic behavior of Erfc function [https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4262695/inequivalence-of-fourier-transform/4262783?noredirect=1#comment8866876_4262783]

Comment: @sined: Sorry, you still don't present any Mathematica code for your claim " I have →1 for x→0". BTW, there is no `x` in the codes from your question.

Comment: @user64494 thank you for your comment. I have added the code with the corresponding limit to my original post.

Answer (score 1):

Since the real part of the integrand is symmetric about t1==t2, simply double the integral and integrate t2 from zero to t1 with no problems.The imaginary part is antisymmetric and disappears. Therefore work only with `Cos`

By the way, this is no improper integral, as limit t2->t1 is a finite number. `Limit[\[Delta]Et\[Delta]E0[t1, t2, 1, 1]*E^(I*1*(t1 - t2)), t2 -> t1]` is `1/4`

**Edit**

Add exclusions to avoid overflow at t1==t2 where only limit is defined.

```
Nint[t_, \[CapitalOmega]_] := 
  2 NIntegrate[\[Delta]Et\[Delta]E0[t1, t2, 1, 1]*Cos[\[CapitalOmega] (t1 - t2)], {t1, 
    0, t}, {t2, 0, t1}, Exclusions -> t1 == t2]

Nint[10, 1]

(*   1.73825   *)
```

Comment: Just to make sure I am following, are you using the following identity? 
$\frac{1}{2}\int_{t_{0}}^{t}dt_{1}\int_{t_{0}}^{t}dt_{2}V_{I}\left(t_{1}-t_{2}\right)e^{i\Omega\left(t_{1}-t_{2}\right)}=\int_{t_{0}}^{t}dt_{1}\int_{t_{0}}^{t_{1}}dt_{2}V_{I}\left(t_{1}-t_{2}\right)e^{i\Omega\left(t_{1}-t_{2}\right)}$

Comment: This is only valid for the given integrand. Have al look with `Plot3D[\[Delta]Et\[Delta]E0[t1, t2, 1, 1]*Cos[(t1 - t2)], {t1, 0, 
  10}, {t2, 0, 10}] `  and for imaginary part with Sin instead Cos.

Comment: I have tried to perform the integration as suggested by you, but I'm still encountering some issues.

Comment: i am working with version "8.0 for Microsoft Windows (32-bit) (December 9, 2010)". May be other versions react different.

Comment: What is if you try integrate t2 from t1 to t  `Nint[t_, \[CapitalOmega]_] := 
 2 NIntegrate[\[Delta]Et\[Delta]E0[t1, t2, 1, 1]*
    Cos[\[CapitalOmega] (t1 - t2)], {t1, 0, t}, {t2, t1, t}, 
   Exclusions -> t1 == t2] `

Comment: Interesting. If I add:
     MaxRecursion -> 50, WorkingPrecision -> 20, Method -> \
"DoubleExponential"  
I get the value you have but with warning: 

NIntegrate::ncvi: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 50 iterated refinements in t2 in the region {{0,1.0000000000000000000},{0,1.0000000000000000000}}. NIntegrate obtained -0.4604536531277465246461783495977263581139142437508622462141497737684296 and 0.00001019141586517510846929086626158893156569235869306953431086376073293079`70. for the integral and error estimates.